# Get table rows HTTP API in JSON

Tags: cleos, table

When I try to get table using

```
curl --request POST \                                                                                               
  --url http://bp.cryptolions.io:8888/v1/chain/get_table_rows \
  --data '{"table":"global","scope":"eosio","code":"eosio","limit":10}'
```

I get the binary format:

```
{"rows":["0000100000000000e8030000000008000c000000f40100001400000064000000400d0300e8030000f049020064000000100e00005802000080533b0000100000040006000000000010000000a1deb0e00d00000072e292390f0000000ff59b4560b5958914700500a447800e00000000aa56e30100000000ff430100865ce6a59102000000e15fd7136f0500150072bf769f2819dd4300000000"],"more":false}
```

But when I use

```
/opt/eosio/bin/cleos -u http://bp.cryptolions.io:8888 get table eosio eosio rammarket
```

I get expected result as JSON

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
      "base": {
        "balance": "8895932725 RAM",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      },
      "quote": {
        "balance": "7724878.7130 EOS",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Wondering why HTTP API produces such results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output was in binary format.
If you need the output as json then add "json":true in the data as shown in the command below

```
curl --request POST 
--url http://bp.cryptolions.io:8888/v1/chain/get_table_rows 
--data '{"table":"global","scope":"eosio","code":"eosio","limit":10,"json":true}'
```